# Changing legend in ArcGIS Online for use in a Dashboard

Tags: arcgis-online, legend, operations-dashboard

Working in ArcGIS Online, I have a data set that has 3 types of line data in it , Plow, Grader, and Sweeping.  I have created copies of that layer and filtered out each type of the line work I want to show..... but in the legend it is still showing the other two sets of data.  How do I only show in the legend what I would like it to show...

[image: legend]